# how to connect react native frontend to python backend?

Tags: react-native, tensorflow

Working on a mobile app with React native, and i have a bunch of tensorflow code that i would like to run input from the user through. How could i take user input from the mobile app, and send it to a backend where its run through the tensorflow?

i know it has something to do with flask maybe, and/or perhaps a cloud service. But i really don't know where to start, or how to think about it.

Comment: You need to build rest api with flask. go with flask boilerplate or starter kits https://github.com/antkahn/flask-api-starter-kit

Comment: Did you tried tensor flow lite for android ?: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/android

Comment: Doesn’t need to run any predictions on device